# Expression evaluates to false in for loop whereas it's true in if

Tags: bash, for

This command outputs PID of process listening on port 8083:

`lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t`

When there is no process, it returns empty string. No process is running on that port so I am checking if that command returns empty string

```
if [[ -z $(lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t) ]]; then
    echo "waiting for startup"
else
    echo "process is listening on port 8083"
fi
```

it outputs "waiting for startup" like expected, but when I am doing:

```
for (( ; -z $(lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t) ; )); do
    echo "waiting for startup"
    sleep 1
done
```

it does not output anything, but this condition was true when it was evaluated in `if` so if it's true then this loop should execute `do...done` block and print "processing", but it does not and exits immediately. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[ … ]]` evaluates a [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). In a conditional expression, `-z` is an operator which takes a string as argument and returns true if the string is empty and false otherwise.

In `for ((…; …; …))`, each of the three semicolon-separated parts inside the double parentheses is an [arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic). In an arithmetic expression, `-` is the negation or subtraction operator. `z` is a reference to the variable `z`, evaluating to 0 if the variable is not defined. So when the output of `lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t` is empty and `z` is not defined, the expression evaluates to 0, so the loop exits. When the output is not empty, it's likely to result in a syntax error in the arithmetic expression. What you wrote just doesn't make sense in an arithmetic expression.

This form of `for` is designed for iterations determined by arithmetic, typically counting from some initial value to some final value. You seem to want a while loop, so write a while loop, and use a conditional expression.

```
while [[ -z $(lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t) ]]; do
    echo "waiting for startup"
    sleep 1
done
```

See also [parentheses, brackets and braces in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash/6270803#6270803).

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a `for` loop instead of `while`?

```
while [[ -z $(lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t) ]]
do
    echo "waiting for startup"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I use for because I want to add iterating to that loop like that: `(( i=1; i<=5 && ! -z $(lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t) ; i++ )); do echo ...` . I simplified my example for clarity. Anyway, "use another loop" is not an answer. What do you mean I test against `else`? I used the same exact condition which returned true and did not flow to `else` block. Ok, I think I know what you mean. "Processing doesn't mean port is open. "Processing" means port is not open I am doing some processing in the meantime. I'll change this message,

Comment: count inside the loop and add you condition

Comment: @Kiwy Yes, I know I can do that, but I want to use `for` loop. It should work. Your comment is not an answer to my question. Just like roaima answer is not an answer to my question. Probably you upvoted it, but it does not answer my qeustion too and is just wrong, because he misunderstood my intent.

Comment: @ctomek The expressions inside `for (( ... ))` are evaluated as arithmetic expressions. It's not the same as in `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok, thanks. This seems like an actual answer to my question. Please create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ctomek I answered the question _as asked_. If you had simplified your loop for the purposes of the question that's great, but next time please tell us.

Comment: @Kiwy Don't try to be smartass here, ok? : ) I want to do somehting like `(( i=1; i<=5 && ! -z $(lsof -i4TCP:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN -t) ; i++ )); do echo ...` and it's sensible to use for, That's it.

Comment: @roaima It was clear enough. I get true in `if`, I don't get the same in `for`. Extremely simple. Can't express it clearer than "this condition was true when it was evaluated in if so if it's true then this loop should execute do...done block and print "processing"" And your interpretation of echo "processing" was just wrong and that's the issue. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: @ctomek I'm not doing the smartass, just saying that using the right tool for the right function is always better. `for` is an iterative loop `while` a conditional one. And I'm no master in `bash` and I try to stick away from complex oneliners like yours. it's way to tricky to maintain and understand when you're not the person who originally wrote it.

Comment: @roaima Even if I wouldn't simplify then it's still valid question and still "use another loop" is not answer. May be eventually addition to real answer, but not be the answer itself. Even if `while` makes more sense to be used, then still I'd like to know why `for` doesn't work... Even just for theoretical knowledge.

Comment: @Kiwy Ok, but next time you can do it in normal way like now, not treating me like idiot. : ) "I would just keep telling you to use your hammer not a screw driver to hammer a nail."

Comment: @ctomek It wasn't insulting at least not in my mouth, it was a way to express the way I felt when you ask specifically to use a for loop. I like to be a bit sarcastic but I try not to insult sorry if you take that badly.

Comment: @Kiwy Ok, no problem.